# Why the background sound keep repeating?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have one background sound to use in my project. But when I click the button to other scene, the sound repeats themselves and worse, it redundant with the sound in next scene. I was trying to use one background song for the whole project but this problem happened. Can teach me how?

I am using Adobe Flash CS6. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

the sound is repeating itself because timeline is repeating by default and you should add command `stop()` in actionscript. You did not provide any source code so I'll assume you don't have any, in your case here is a sample program in actionscript that loops the background music.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

stop();   //<-- make sure to stop timeline
var bgMusic:Sound = new BGMusic(); 
var bgChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
bgChannel = bgMusic.play();
bgChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loop);

startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startGame);

function startGame(e:MouseEvent):void {
    gotoAndStop(1, "Scene 2");    //<-- stop after clicking button
}

function loop(e:Event):void {
    bgChannel = bgMusic.play();
    bgChannel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, loop);
}
```